# PHP - Comparing two files and erroring lines that don't match

Tags: php

Ok, so I've had a look around and couldn't find anything.
I'm using this on a site I am creating as the client is notorious for removing company branding and adding his own.

The index.php file has the following check in it, but I want it to be able to output what lines differ if they are not identical.

```
$orgf = 'http://example.com/originalindex.php'; //Original File
$curf = 'index.php'; //This File
$safe = FALSE;
$error = "";
if (file_get_contents($orgf) == file_get_contents($curf)) { $safe = TRUE; } else { $safe = FALSE; $error = $error."Original index.php file has been modified<br/>"; }
```

Thanks, Matt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this possibly, though it would be best to use proper paths to the files.

```
$differences=array_diff( file( $orgf ), file( $curf ) );
$safe=( empty( $differences ) ) ? true : false;

/*Show the differences */
echo '<pre>',print_r( $differences, true ),'</pre>';
```

Because these are 0-indexed arrays, the lines that are different appear to be index+1.

Comment: I integrated it like so and it works great.

 $orgf = 'http://example.com/originalindex.php';
 $curf = 'index.php';
 $safe = FALSE;
 $error = "";
 if (file_get_contents($orgf) == file_get_contents($curf)) {
  $safe = TRUE;
 } else {
  $safe = FALSE;
  $error = $error."<br/>Original index.php file has been modified<br/>";
  foreach(array_diff( file( $orgf ), file( $curf ) ) as $child) {
      $error = $error.$child."<br/>";
  }
  $error = $error."<br/>";
 }

Anyway I could get it to also output the line number of each difference it finds.